# SSIS - Assign the value of a package variable to the ConnectionString of a project connection

Tags: variables, ssis, connection-string

I have a project in SSIS that is automatically deployed and has a number of project connections. These connections are SQL connections that are used in various packages. The main feature of these SQL connections is that they are static, i.e. they never change from packet to packet, the database IP and the database name are always the same.

The problem is that I have to create a project connection for some Excel sources. The peculiarity of this point is that the files will not always have the same name, since they have the format "XXXXX_YYYYYYYMMDD.xlsx", so every month the value of YYYYYYYMMDD will change.

Is there any way to assign the value of a package variable to the ConnectionString of a project connector?

I am aware that this can easily be done through an expression by selecting the ConnectionString and using the Expression Builder to use package variables, but it is not possible to use package variables in project connections.

So to summarize, my question is: Is there any way to assign in each package the value of a variable to a project connector? So that I can use the same connector in different packages and in each one it points to a different source.

The value of the variable would contain the complete ConnectionString.

Thank you very much in advance.

I have tried to use package variables in the project connector, but it doesn't let me, it only lets me use project parameters.

Creating project parameters is not feasible, since they would be obsolete month by month when changing the YYYYYYMMDDD.

Using package connections would fix the problem, but I think that the project does not allow to use them because they could not be deployed automatically.